# Custom close reason stats should link to the question(s)

Tags: feature-request, status-review, 10k-tools, custom-close-reasons

I'm reviewing recent custom close reasons in the 10k tools (/tools/question-close-stats) and there are some I'd like to take issue with...

The problem is, the reasons are listed with no link to either the comments or the questions that they were used on. This means it's practically impossible for me to find out which question(s) they were used on and by whom (there is no way to search comments or closed questions by custom reason AFAIK, without using SEDE possibly).

The 10k tools "Close" tab (/tools?tab=close) only allows you to list questions by top level close reasons so that doesn't help much (I'd have to manually check through all the "off-topic" questions).

**Could the Close Stats page link to the relevant questions?**

---

A quick mockup of what this could look like (i.e. each row is an expandable list of links):

[image]

<sup>(I've sorted out the messed up column widths and given the rows a bit of padding in that mockup too so if we could fix that while we're at it that would be super cool, please, thanks.)</sup>

Answer (score 16):

#### Why this matters

**These stats are a great way to spot bad close reasons**. Here's a sampling:

- I’m voting to close this question because.
- I’m voting to close this question because it should be closed
- I’m voting to close this question because you are hunting points and not looking for help (Asked and answered at the same time)
- I’m voting to close this question because this is not a "please provide me with code" site
- `set` is probably as fast as you'll get in just python as it's already implemented in `C`.
- I’m voting to close this question because it contains sensitive personal informations (ssh username/password)
- I’m voting to close this question because it asks users on how to solve a problem, without any actual effort demonstrated, and effectively asks others to write code for them.
- I’m voting to close this question because the OP has solved it himself.
- I’m voting to close this question because probably homework.
- I’m voting to close this question because OP needs to show some effort.
- Just swapping "http" to "https" only changes the protocol, but you didn't tell it which certificate to actually use. See the official Node.js tutorial on setting up an HTTPS server for what's left to do on your side.
- I’m voting to close this question because this question is unrealistic, it amounts to wanting to change the script of another web page present in another tab of a browser
- I’m voting to close this question because This question is about the HTML <center> element which has been removed from the relevant web standards
- I’m voting to close this question because the issue is due to an old version of pandas
- I’m voting to close this question because it is apparently a school project, and the asker did not make any clear attempt to solve it themselves.
- I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in the comments.
- I’m voting to close this question because no effort has been shown to solve the problem.
- I’m voting to close this question because no research
- I’m voting to close this question because it’s too nonsensical for someone with this high of rep to ask.
- I’m voting to close this question because the question is already posted here [port Node and TreeBuilder from python to c++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/284429/port-node-and-treebuilder-from-python-to-c) and already has an answer
- I’m voting to close this question because StackOverflow is not a free coding service. It is powered by human beings. Maybe try a generative AI for a solution. Though your best option is to learn programming and show your own efforts if you need help from the community here.
- I’m voting to close this question because this is not an R problem. The remote server is rejecting requests because the user's rate limit has been exceeded.

None of these are good close reasons (a few of them even look like an answer!)—and that's just <del>what I could find offhand to write this answer</del> what I found in a handful of checks.  The trouble is, it's very hard to actually find the original questions these were posted on to do anything about it, such as flagging for moderator attention.  Your best bet is often a web search, with which I've had very inconsistent success.  SEDE can help too, but only with comments posted before the last dump and not deleted.