# Disallow the Zero Width Joiner (U+200D) character in a custom close reason

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, custom-close-reasons

The current top custom close vote reason on Stack Overflow is "ಠ_ಠ" with a bunch of Zero Width Joiner characters appended to the end.

[image: ಠ_ಠ]

While I appreciate the humor, this really isn't an appropriate close reason.  Just as null characters and Zero-Width Spaces are disallowed, so should Zero Width Joiners.

Comment: [Custom close reason stats should link to the question(s)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294590/230261) sure would be nice.

Answer (score 28):

I could write a regex to block these. But instead, I messaged the person responsible with a long, eloquent plea for sanity. Seemed easier.

Comment: Clearly I hat fun.  Thanks Shog.  If this issue comes up in the future, will you consider implementing the regex?

Comment: I will unless I won't

Comment: "with a long, eloquent plea for sanity" hah!

Comment: Good inch square on my screen!

Comment: Hey - how did the plea work out?